# Cross tab .jasper file error when running

Tags: crosstab

I am getting the following error when i tried to call .jasper file in servlet.

The .jasper is having crosstab, which run perfectly in design IDE in ireport 4.5

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from InputStream
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:196)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:361)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:163)
        at ReportManager.annualSaleReports.processRequest(annualSaleReports.java:103)
        at ReportManager.annualSaleReports.doPost(annualSaleReports.java:317)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: net.sf.jasperreports.crosstabs.base.JRBaseCrosstabGroup; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6144263542628036271, local class serialVersionUID = 7685014062058258277
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor193.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:192)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, this happen due to when compiled version not compatible or not equal to running .jasper.jar version